# Valsalva maneveuer cycle in romanian deadlift

Tags: deadlifts

Normally in a deadlift you brace before you pull, and you hold till it comes back to the floor.

Now, in Romanian, there is a constant tension on your body. So I would like to ask what is the proper time in the motion to brace?

Comment: What do you mean by 'brace'? Brace what?

Comment: abdominal muscles ofc "Ethan

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but an RDL is pretty much the same as a conventional deadlift except keeping almost straight legs and and RDL starts at the top goes down to just above the floor and then ends back at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the confusion is because you're performing the Valsalva Maneuver which is possible in deadlifts because you can always breath and reset at the bottom after each rep.  RDLs don't have any time to reset, so holding your breath throughout the entire set would be detrimental.

The answer is you breath at the top. Once you're standing upright, exhale, but keep your core tight.  Then just before descending, breath in to your stomach as much as you can. Perform the rep then exhale as your rising or once upright again.  Just repeat the cycle until the set is done.

Comment: Your timing doesn't seem right. Generally it's said that you should inhale during the eccentric, and exhale during the concentric. So in going down, out going up.

Comment: @Ethan I'm saying inhale before the eccentric before you lower. I don't know how you could inhale when you're holding a bar outright during the eccentric.  There's way too much pressure on the body.

Comment: What I'm saying is inhale at the top like you said, hold it during the eccentric, snd exhale as you pull back up. Unless I'm mistaken, it seems like your answer says to inhale at the top perform the full rep, and then exhale at the top again. Holding it for a while rep, through the concentric, is what can cause you to pass out.

Comment: @Ethan “inhale during the eccentric” Doing this on RDLs is an exceptionally terrible idea.

Comment: @Ethan. You're right. You can exhale through the concentric, but I don't think you'd pass out waiting until the end unless you were doing a really long eccentric. The way I described is how I do them. I wouldn't breath out at the bottom though. At least wait half way through the concentric.